# magento2 : minicart not updates after add products to cart

Tags: magento2

when submit form 
Only first product **price** was **display** and **other** product **price shows 0**
sections.xml created

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
          <action name="frontname/controller/action">
             <section name="cart"/>
          </action>
      </config>
```

**controller file**

```
 foreach ($pid as $value) {

            if (isset($value)) {
           $this->addCartProduct($value);
        }
         $this->_cart->save();

        }

public function addCartProduct($productID){
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productID);
$info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
    [
        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
        'product_id' => $productID,
        // 'price' => $product->setPrice($price),
         //'qty' => 1,
        // 'price' => 100,

    ]
);
return $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $info);
}
```

**Note :** I also tried to pass price and qty in function.

Comment: Can you please upload your controller code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this below code in your controller :

You should add foreach of product collection instead of product ids array.

```
protected $formKey;
protected $_productFactory;
protected $_cart;
protected $messageManager;
protected $collectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $pid = "Your product ids array";
    $cart_product = $this->collectionFactory->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $pid));
    if ($cart_product) {
        foreach ($cart_product as $key => $value) {
            $custom_optinons_value = '';
            if (isset($value['super_attribute']) || !empty($value['super_attribute'])) {
                $custom_optinons_value = $value['super_attribute'];
            }
            $this->addCartProduct($value['id'], $value['qty'], $custom_optinons_value);
        }
        $this->_cart->save();
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Shopping cart updated succesfully.');
}

public function addCartProduct($productID, $productQty, $config_options)
{
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productID);
    $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $productID,
            'qty' => $productQty,
            'super_attribute' => $config_options,
        ]
    );
    return $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $info);
}
```

Remove var and generated folder.

Comment: it shows error undefined **Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory::getCollection()**

Comment: $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection() write like this.

Comment: i tried already this but getting wired error
**Warning: PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string**

Comment: See my updated answer. Remove var and generated

Comment: same error :: **Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::getCollection()**

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to remove Factory from \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection. Now try it.

Comment: same error **getCollection** undefined

Comment: please upload your whole file.